# In Excel, need to populate a cell with a value based on multiple conditions in corresponding table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am editing this entire thing because I feel I can be more clear now, and I think this question can be very useful for a lot of people:

[image: Screen Capture]
Original image here: http://i.imgur.com/Givg96T.png?1[/img]

I guess I can't post a picture, so here is a link to what I am referencing.

Based on the shown formula, Cell D1 says compliant because it found the referenced text (B1) in the cited range column (D). This is fine, I get how to do this part. The problem is that I want it to say compliant only if it finds that text, which it did, AND ALSO has a Y next to that particular cell in column G, not a N as shown. So ideally it would say 'not sufficient' rather than compliant, because although it found the next, there is an N next to it, not a Y. This needs to apply to a range and not just one row as there will be many rows of this same data.

Essentially the question I want cell D1 to answer is this: Do you find anything that says the contents of cell B1 in column D? And if so, is there a Y next to it in column G? If the answer is yes to both of those questions, say "compliant". If not, say 'Not sufficient'.

Thank you to anyone who can offer any advice, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome. Nobody is here to write you the code, so show us what have you tried so far. What is working and what not.

Comment: Okay, right now I have: =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B3,$F$10:$F$406,0)),"Not Sufficient","Compliant")

Comment: This gives me a 'sufficient' or 'not sufficient' based on if the referenced category is present (B3), but it pays no attention to whether the G column says Y or N for that particular row. This is the part I am trying to incorporate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **IF** and **AND** both in this case.
You can try the formula (assuming value starts from row 1):

```
=IF(AND(F1="international stock",G1="Y"),"Yes","No")
```

Put it in cell **H1** and drag to the end of rows in column **H**.
For the demo purpose I have put "Local stock" as well.

Hers is the screenshot.

[image]

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**EDIT** (Based on comment):
**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

So in order to search in whole column, you will first have to create a name range for column F and G so it will make your life easier.

Formulas -> Name Manager -> Create new -> give name **RngF** (for column F) and give the formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$F$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$F:$F),1)
```

Same way create another and give a name **RngG** and give formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$G$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$G:$G),1)
```

You may need to change the **"Sheet Name"**.

Then you will combine **IF**, **AND**, **MATCH**, **INDEX** formulas and **Array** to get what you want.
Basically,
**MATCH** will tell you the cell number if "International stock" is present in column **F**.
**INDEX** will give you the cell value based on the references.

And in final formula, you will combine them altogether like this:

```
=IF(AND(MATCH("International stock",RngF,0)>0,INDEX(RngG,MATCH("International stock",RngF,0))="Y"),"Yes","No")
```

Make sure you hit `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`. This will make the formula to run in entire array that you've passed using name range. So it should look something like:

```
{=IF(AND(MATCH("International stock",RngF,0)>0,INDEX(RngG,MATCH("International stock",RngF,0))="Y"),"Yes","No")}
```

Comment: is there a way to make that reference a range instead of one cell? You have it so that if f1='international stock' and g1='y', it will give the right response. But can it search through an entire column and say, if you find 'international stock' in this column, anywhere in this column, and the cell directly to the left says 'y', then return yes?

Comment: Now you are changing your question.

Comment: Use something like `=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100="string")*(B1:B100="y"))>0, "Yes", "")`  for that. Change the ranges and strings to your needs.

Comment: @Nelly27281 That worked perfectly for what I needed, thank you so much for your help.